# How can I get one of my foreign key outputs to repeat in a merge transformation in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, merge, ssis, foreign-keys, etl

I tried asking this question before and it seemed to have gotten swept under the rug.

First thing first, here are these two pictures to show the table structure and the current output I get in SSIS.

*Table Diagram*
[image: Table Diagram]

*Current Output*
[image: Current Output]

So in table three, there is only one entry. This entry (name) applies to the other foreign keys though. What I want the final output to look like is like my current output, but instead of the NULLS, there should just be ones.

I was able to get this far on my own through researching and learning about the merge transformations but I can't seem to find anything on manipulating the data in the way that I want.

I greatly appreciate any tips or advice you can offer.

EDIT: Since the images can't be seen apparently, I will try and describe them.

The table diagram has four tables, the top one in the waterfall has a primary key formed from the three foreign keys for the three different tables.

Trying to accomplish filling out this table in SSIS, my output has each foreign key id from the first two tables, but only one in the third table. The rest from the third foreign key are all NULLS. I believe this is because there is only one entry in that table for now, but this entry applies to all of the foreign key ids and so it should be repeating.

It should look like this:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3
1       1       1
2       2       1
3       3       1
```

But instead, I am only getting nulls in the ID3 field after the first record. How do I make the single id repeat in ID3?

EDIT 2: Some additional screenshots of my data flow and merge transformation as requested.

```
[![SSIS Dataflow][3]][3]
```

[image: Merge Transformation Setup]

Comment: I can't see images but to turn a null to 1 use a derived column: isnull(column)?1:column

Comment: I'll try experimenting with that and I'll let you know if it works. Eventually there should be different entries in the third table and those entries could correspond to multiple foreign keys as well. So lots of ones matching for the first twelve and then lots of twos matching for another set of twelve rercords.

Comment: Hi. Do not post the same question twice. Edit the original to improve it. Act on comments. Also on [ask] & other links at [help] especially [mcve] .

Comment: Please use text for text (including tables & DDL), don't use images/links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). See [mcve]. You are not explaining & showing what you are doing. "Output" from what input & query and what is the desired output? (In a form we can run.)

Comment: Ok Phil. How is that? I figured images would be the best way for it to be seen, but didn't know there would be trouble with it. I've tried writing it out. If I don't get an answer, I should just wait and not repost?

Comment: To be able to help you, I would need to see your source data that is producing the "current output" you have posted, and I would need to see your dataflow and the properties of your merge component.   Others might be better at guessing, though.   The image of your table structure isn't particularly useful in this question.

Comment: By source data do you mean what is in Table 1, 2, and 3 that generate the primary keys that are used as foreign keys in the "joining IDs" table? I would gladly share my dataflow, but how should I go about that? Screenshots seem to trigger people...

Comment: At the very least, we need to see the configuration of your Merge Join task.

Comment: @digital.aaron Alright, I've added those two screenshots. I appreciate everyone's input. I'll try and help you guys help me as much as possible. :)

Comment: Will Table3 always have just a single row?

Comment: Table3 can have multiple rows that are all unique. Each unique row in Table3 will likely apply to more than one combination of the IDs from Tables 1 & 2. So let's say in figure [2], in column three of that merge transformation, for rows 1-6, 1 would be in each row. Then from rows 7-12, there would be a 2. I hope that helps, I'm trying to communicate this idea as best I can haha. Thank you so much for your help & interest Aaron!

Comment: How do you determine which IDs in Table1&2 to map a row from Table3 to? In your first example, with only a single row in Table3, it's not apparent why T3id = 1 should be mapped to ID1&ID2 when those values <> 1.

Comment: Ah! That's a good question, probably why this has been hard to solve. I guess my answer to that would be that the original source data is in one giant Access table and I am attempting to normalize it. The IDs in 1 & 2 are tied to the IDs in 3 because they exist together in the original source as one or more entries. Let just say that tables one and two represent attributes of some sort and table three could be a list of the names of the original source data. Does that help?

Comment: Did I lose you Aaron?

Comment: So...I'm not supposed to re-post the question and I've done what I can to improve it, but it seems like it is going to fall into the annals of stack overflow... I've continued to try and find my own answer to the issue, but I am still stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on this for a few weeks, and with a tips from a colleague, a solution to this question was found. Surprisingly, it was quite simple and I'm slightly shocked that no one on here could provide the answer.

The solution was simply this; Using a data source, write the following SQL code in the data access mode (SQL Command):

```
SELECT a.T1ID,
b.T2ID,
c.T3ID 
FROM Table1 AS a join 
Table2 AS b
On a.T1ID = b.T2ID,
Table3 AS c
ORDER BY a.[T1ID] ASC
```

[image: What I Needed]

Answer (score 0):

If Table3 will always have just a single row, the simplest solution would be to use an Execute SQL task to save the T3id to a variable (Control Flow), then use a Derived Column task (Data Flow) to add the variable as a new column.

If that won't work for you (or your data), you can take a look [here](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2010/09/performing-cross-join-cartesian-product.html) to see how to fudge the Merge Join task to do what you want.

Comment: I think this is close to what I'm looking for. I responded to your question above. I am curious what the solution will be when Table3 will have multiple rows. Thanks again.